# ERROR: relation "codepool_codepoolseq_seq" does not exist SQL state: 42P01

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Below is my script but I keep getting an error.

```
-- Table: public.codepool

-- DROP TABLE public.codepool;

CREATE TABLE public.codepool
(
    codepoolseq bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('codepool_codepoolseq_seq'::regclass),
    codenumber character(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT codepool_pkey PRIMARY KEY (codepoolseq)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.codepool
    OWNER to postgres;
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR: relation "codepool_codepoolseq_seq" does not exist SQL state: 42P01

Answer (score 0):

In your Scheme you must have Sequences called `codepool_codepoolseq_seq`

Example create:

```sql
-- SEQUENCE: public.codepool_codepoolseq_seq

-- DROP SEQUENCE public.codepool_codepoolseq_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.codepool_codepoolseq_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.codepool_codepoolseq_seq
    OWNER TO postgres;
```